# which version of Eclipse I should use for Android Development

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am almost confused about these versions of `Eclipse`. There are `indigo` and `Kepler` which can be downloaded from Eclipse website. Another thing is, when I download the `ADT` inside its folder there is another executable file for `Eclipse` that when you execute it, a different logo than the previously mentioned versions appears with title `Android Development Tools`, is it also another version of `Eclipse`?

which one should I use? Or it is all about user preference?

Comment: This sort of question is off-topic for this site, but the answer is: use the ADT bundle: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: FYI, "Indogo" and "Kepler" are just [different versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases); "Kepler" is the more recent one.

Comment: @popovitsj thank you for you answer and your advice. but since there are android developers use eclipse, then it is likely to encounter some related problem. so wht it is off-topic

Comment: @Elpharaoh it's off-topic because it says so in the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Look under point 5.

Comment: @popovitsj ok, sorry then

Comment: @popovitsj i really do not know which AVD should choose and configure, ca i ask a question about that or it's off-topic?

Comment: Yes, `which AVD should choose` is an opinion and thus is considered off-topic. If you are having trouble configuring a specific emulator or are running into a specific problem then you can post a question with what you have tried and ask what you might be able to do to get your emulator working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to download Eclipse and Android SDK separately.Simply download the [ADT bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). It will have Eclipse, Android SDK, SDK manager to download APIs for various versions of android, USB driver etc. it will also have tools like adb. You can use it to start, stop server, view devices etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the adt bundle, that comes bundled with the recomended version of eclipse. Just google that. It has support for all android needs.
Use the eclipse that comes with it, since it has all the needed plugins for developing for android.

Comment: should i download the adt and eclipse also, or just adt?

Comment: Just adt. The eclpse that it comes with is already set up for you with all the pluggins and settings. If you need extra help, refer to thenewboston's first tutorials on android development.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the ADT of the previous answer contains eclipse already.
I am using the ADT as well, but there is also an early access tool, called Android Studio, maybe this is more to your taste?
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: I probably wouldn't recommend AS to *this* op; from your link -> Caution: Android Studio is currently available as an early access preview. Several features are either incomplete or not yet implemented and you may encounter bugs. If you are not comfortable using an unfinished product, you may want to instead download (or continue to use) the ADT Bundle (Eclipse with the ADT Plugin).

Comment: Sure its early access, but since its based on IntelliJ I thought it is worth mentionning. I am using ADT because i am used to it now, but when starting android development i would imagine this might be worth a try.